# TextToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(locale) returns -2 always

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

i am trying to use textToSpeech to translate the user entered text to selected language. For that first i have stored all the Locales available in Locale array.Then in a for loop i am trying to select only those locales those are supported by tts like this

```
for(int j=0;j<locales.length;j++)
{
if(tts.isLanguageAvailable(locales[j])==TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE)
{
       //My Code
}
}
```

But the problem is always `tts.isLanguageAvailable()' returns -2 both in emulator and device.
I don't understand what could be the problem.Locale.US also is not supported it seems! What shall i do?I have also checked the settings..pico TTS is selected and 7 languages are also installed but still none is caught in IF loop.I have tried in both emulator and device

Comment: have You checked the device Settings for TTS? On some devices, TTS is set to Googles TTS (for example Samsung Galaxy S3), this needs an Internet Connection. Go to Settings and choose the Text-To-Speach Settings and set it to Your device´s engine instead of Googles engine. Maybe this is the problem

Comment: okay i just checked.googles TTS was selected.other one available in Pico tts.Should i select Pico TTS?

Comment: yes, try it. On my device I selected Samsung TTS and then it worked offline

Comment: I don't have access to my system now I'll let you know once i have.one more problem is for most of the locales there is no country available.and pico shows only 6 or 7 languages.Is there any way to install more?

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but for future visitors: It seems like Google TTS needs a bit to initialize, so the first invocation of isLanguageAvailable always returned -2 for me as well. I used Handler.postDelayed( ..., 500 ) as a workaround. It works, but I wish I knew a better way.
btw: You should do some >= comparision instead of == LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE. In most cases, just having the language is good enough. Who cares about a british or american accent? ;)

Comment: For future, future visitors, I don't have the problem of isLanguageAvailable returning -2 (LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) the first time. I do have the problem, however, of a LANG_AVAILABLE locale not being speakable. It seems this happens when the locale is classified as "networkTts" only (from call to getFeatures(locale)). I presume this means that the language is synthesized via the network, instead of locally. However, even when I have network connectivity, the Google TTS engine still does not speak if the local is set to one that is "networkTts". I believe this is must be a bug.

Comment: Also, regarding the statement above that Google TTS engine requires an internet connection, this is not true for locally installed languages. Presumably, for "networkTts" locales, it would require network connectivity, but, as my previous post states, there is an issue with this even.